# How would I generate random numbers that satisfy a specific ratio in C++?

Tags: c++, random, probability

Consider this piece of contrived code in the context of generating trees for a game:

```cpp
// Pretend there's some code somewhere that associates the 0-100 number to its corresponding size.
enum class TreeSize : uint32_t
{
    Small, // 0-9
    Medium, // 10-60
    Large,// 61-90
    ExtraLarge, // 91-100

};

// returns tree size
int GenerateTree()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937_64 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int32_t> dist(0, 100);

   return dist(s_mt);
}
```

**Let's say I want to generate 1000 trees, but bound to a specific ratio of tree sizes**. For example:

- Small trees: 15%
- Medium trees: 30%
- Large trees:  40%
- Extra large trees: 15%

How would I do that? **Is there something off the shelf that accomplishes this?** Surely this is a problem many people have had to contend with before, yeah?

Comment: There are a lot of different distribution options in the standard library  (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) - have you taken a look at those? E.g.: maybe you want [`std::piecewise_constant_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_constant_distribution`)

Answer (score 6):

What you want is [`std::discrete_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution), where you can specify probability weights for each item separately:

```
int GenerateTree()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937_64 mt(rd());
    std::discrete_distribution<int32_t> dist({15, 30, 40, 15});

    return dist(s_mt);
}
```

Comment: And then, after having picked a general size, use a `std::uniform_int_distribution` to generate the actual size in the interval corresponding to the picked general size.

Comment: @j6t If the variation within the tree size class is needed, `std::piecewise_constant_distribution` from [bitmask's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75508904/624664) would be better, as it does both steps simultaneously.

Comment: Except that `std::piecewise_constant_distribution` works only with floating point numbers, which has quite a few cornercases when it must be converted to a discrete distribution.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a floating point number with the specified distribution with `std::piecewise_constant_distribution`. But note that you should keep the mt object around, not initialise it every time anew.

```
struct TreeGenerator {
    std::mt19937 mt;
    TreeGenerator() : mt{std::random_device{}()} {}

    double operator()() {
        std::vector<double> i{0,  10, 61, 91, 101};
        std::vector<double> w{15, 30, 40, 15};
        std::piecewise_constant_distribution<double> dist(i.begin(), i.end(), w.begin());
        return dist(mt);
    }
};
```

[Here's a live example of how to use this.](https://godbolt.org/z/P4hqbnTKM)